# How do I resolve the following errors while creating a Phoenix project using Mix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am following the Phoenix Guide to learn web development using Phoenix. I installed all the prerequisites. Following is my development environment:

```
Ubuntu     : 16.04 (xenial) x86 64bit  
Phoenix    : 1.2.1  
Elixir     : 1.3.3  
hex        : 0.13.2  
Erlang/OTP : 19  
NodeJS     : 6.9.1  
PostgreSQL : 9.5.4  
brunch     : 2.9.1  
npm        : 3.10.8
```

To create a project, as specified in the *Up And Running* section of the guide, I issued the following command:

```
mix phoenix.new hello_phoenix
```

Then I was prompted for fetching and installing the dependencies. I answered yes to the question, but then I get the following error and the control returns to the Linux command prompt:

```
Fetch and install dependencies? [Yn] Y
* running mix deps.get
* error command failed to execute, please run the following command again after installation: "mix deps.get"
* running npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build
* error command failed to execute, please run the following command again after installation: "npm install && node node_modules/brunch/bin/brunch build"
```

As instructed in the error message, when I issue the *mix deps.get* command on the linux command prompt I get the following error:

```
** (Mix) Could not find a Mix.Project, please ensure a mix.exs file is available
```

So I issued the same command from the newly created project directory _hello_phoenix_ and get the following error:

```
A new Hex version is available (v0.13.2), please update with `mix local.hex`
Running dependency resolution
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Access.Map.get_and_update!/3 is undefined (module Access.Map is not available)
    Access.Map.get_and_update!(%Mix.Dep{app: :phoenix, deps: [], extra: [], from: "/home/CookieButter/Projects/Phoenix/hello_phoenix/mix.exs", manager: nil, opts: [env: :prod, hex: :phoenix, build: "/home/CookieButter/Projects/Phoenix/hello_phoenix/_build/dev/lib/phoenix", dest: "/home/CookieButter/Projects/Phoenix/hello_phoenix/deps/phoenix"], requirement: "~> 1.2.1", scm: Hex.SCM, status: {:unavailable, "/home/CookieButter/Projects/Phoenix/hello_phoenix/deps/phoenix"}, top_level: true}, :deps, #Function<11.61161633/1 in Hex.Resolver.attach_dep_and_children/3>)
    lib/hex/resolver.ex:190: Hex.Resolver.attach_dep_and_children/3
    lib/hex/resolver.ex:150: Hex.Resolver.get_deps/4
    lib/hex/resolver.ex:109: Hex.Resolver.activate/5
    lib/hex/resolver.ex:31: Hex.Resolver.resolve/3
    lib/hex/remote_converger.ex:33: Hex.RemoteConverger.converge/2
    (mix) lib/mix/dep/converger.ex:89: Mix.Dep.Converger.all/4
    (mix) lib/mix/dep/converger.ex:50: Mix.Dep.Converger.converge/4
```

Please note the top line of the error message which suggests that I should update Hex to new version 0.13.2. But I already have that version on my machine.

Because I am new to Phoenix, I am not able to understand the errors(I think this is related to some of the dependencies not available).

How do I resolve these errors?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I resolved the issue.

The problem was with a stale(?) *hex.ez* file in the directory *~/.mix/archives/*. After I removed that file by issuing the command *mix archive.uninstall hex.ez*, everything is now working fine.

I don't know where the *hex.ez* file came from though. Could be a problem with upgrading mechanism of *hex*.

I hope this helps anyone facing similar issue.